# replace a line in linux file containing special characters

Tags: linux, replace, character, line, special-characters

Here is an extract from a script showing the variables for the script

```
PathToPiconPNG="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/19.2E/"
PathToOscamSrvid="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/19.2E/oscam.srvid"
PathToPiconTPL="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/oscam_picons/"
PathToTmp="/tmp/"
```

I want to run this script numerous times replacing (for example) this line:

```
PathToPiconPNG="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/19.2E/"
```

with this lines

```
PathToPiconPNG="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/28.2E/"
```

I have tried using sed (I know this example is wrong but you might get what im trying to achieve)

```
sed 's/{PathToPiconPNG="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/19.2E/"}/{PathToPiconPNG="/var/OscamSrvidPicon/picon/28.2E/"}/g' filename.txt > newfilenam.txt
```

If that is not possible, is there any way that I can set the variable externally from another script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/picon\/.+\//picon\/28.2E\//' filename.txt > newfilenam.txt
```

Comment: `sed` uses Basic RE, so `+` is not a special character. Also, since you're not doing minimal matching, there's a chance that you're replacing too much, such as if there are further slashes later on in the same line.

Comment: I made some changes that I think will pass for this case.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant.. The only problem is that "picon/ occurs quiet a few times in this file and I do not want to replace it everywhere..  Can I make this sed target a specific row containing the line in question that will be constant..

Comment: you want to specify what lines will match? use `-n 16224,16482p` and replace the numbers with your line range

Comment: Thanks Paul but I don't really understand whether I have to specify the line range within the sed command or how it fits into the sed command?  Would it be something like this? `sed -n 5,6p -E 's/picon\/.+\//picon\/28.2E\//' filename.txt > newfilenam.txt`

Comment: OK, Thanks Paul.. I will test & report back..  As I am new on this site I am not able to rate your answer as useful but I can assure you it was very useful.

Comment: Paul your first example worked perfect, can you please explain what we are asking in that example as I am a bit lost even though it worked 100%

Comment: `sed` is the program. `-E` fixes @ChrisJester-Young's comment. `.+` means 1 or more characters. ummm what am I missing?

Comment: OK, its great Paul, works perfect, I just cant understand why it did not replace all occurrences of /picon with /picon/28.2E/   I mean, how did it know only to replace /picon/19.2E/ with /picon/28.2E/

Comment: your version is strict. 19.2E is a literal comparison. The answer I provided uses a wild card or meta character to tell sed that I want a pattern to be matched.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz `-E` is not a [standard option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) for `sed`, and even for [GNU `sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html), the most common `sed` implementation on GNU/Linux systems, the option for using Extended RE is `-r`, not `-E`.

Comment: OK, I have script working using `sed -E 's/picon\/.+\//picon\/28.2E\//' filename.txt > newfilenam.txt` but to further automate my script, I would like to be able to replace the 28.2E above with a variable i.e. `sed -E 's/picon\/.+\//picon\/$282E\//' filename.txt > newfilenam.txt`  But If i use the second method, Instead of searching for the text string in the variable $282E and placing it in the new file, it just prints $282E to the new file

Comment: To put it simply, I would like to tell sed to replace text in new file with the text string associated with a variable..

Comment: please ignore last 2 comments, I see that I just need to add quotes to the variable...